# Reversing the direction of a trackball

Tags: configuration

For some reason, I want to  use a trackball Logitech (aka Logicool) Marble Mouse (aka Trackman Marble) upside down. Is there a way to reverse the left and right rolling and up and bottom rolling respectively software-wise, without modifying the hardware? I tried this by writing a configuration file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.g/` such as

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Marble Mouse"
    MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
    Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
    Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"
    Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 5 4 7 6 2 2"
EndSection
```

The crucial part is that I switched the keys 4 and 5 and 6 and 7 so that instead of:

```
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 2"
```

I have:

```
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 5 4 7 6 2 2"
```

But this is not working, and this maybe only valid for scroll wheel emulation mode. How can I reverse the rolling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gaming we just refer to this as "invert mouse".

From the [Xorg mouse(4) man page](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R7.0/doc/html/mouse.4.html):

```
Option "InvX" "boolean"
    Invert the X axis. Default: off. 
Option "InvY" "boolean"
    Invert the Y axis. Default: off.
```

Comment: You may are using `evdev` instead of `mouse` - have a look at http://linux.die.net/man/4/evdev - it may be `InvertY` and `InvertX`

Comment: JodieC and @Ulrich Thanks. I tried this answer along the suggestion of Ulrich. I tried InvertX and InvertY, and it worked (Haven't tried InvX, InvY).

Answer (score 0):

Is the a way to reverse the scrolling if you are using `xinput` as below:

```
xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB Trackball" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
xinput set-int-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 8
xinput set-int-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 8 6 7 4 5
xinput set-int-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation X Axis" 8 6
xinput set-int-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "Evdev Drag Lock Buttons" 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I found the correct solution. I have a Kensington Orbit trackball, so adapt the "sed" string accordingly.

```
## Invert mouse axels, two button trackball
for id in $(xinput --list | sed -n '/Kensington USB\/PS2 Orbit/s/.*=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p')
do
  # Shift left-right mousebutton 3 _ 1 disable all other 0 0 0 0
  xinput set-button-map $id 3 0 1 0 0 0 0   
  # Invert mouse axels. see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation
  xinput set-prop $id 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have "Primax Kensington Eagle Trackball"：

[image]

You just need to set **Natural Scrolling** to 1:

```
xinput --set-prop 'Primax Kensington Eagle Trackball' 278 1
```

I find that when the trackball is plugged into my laptop or into
my desktop, the `xinput` option numbers appear different, even
though both machines are running Ubuntu.

Here is the `xinput` options for my laptop:
[image]

When the trackball is plugged into my desktop, the number `278` is
now `303`.